# Is test or [ or [[ more portable both between bash shells and between other shells?

Tags: shell, posix, test, portability

I see I can do

```
$ [ -w /home/durrantm ] && echo "writable"
writable
```

or

```
$ test -w /home/durrantm && echo "writable"
writable
```

or

```
$ [[ -w /home/durrantm ]] && echo "writable"
writable
```

I like using the third syntax. Are they equivalent in all ways and for all negative and edge cases? Are there any differences in portability, e.g. between bash on Ubuntu and on OS X or older/newer bash versions, e.g. before/after 4.0 and do they both expand expressions the same way?

Comment: For `[ … ]` vs `[[ … ]]` vs `test …`, there are more complete answers in [this mostly duplicate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash).

Comment: For the specific issue of testing for writability of a file, see also [How to non-invasively test for write access to a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159557/80216)

Comment: There is a saying: "there is no portable code, only code that has been ported". My advice with regards to this: Use the most readable form (probably [[ ... ]]) and try it on all platforms you want to support. There is not much use in obscuring your scripts so they run on ancient platforms that neither you nor your target audience uses. It will just make your code hard to read, introduce unnecessary bugs and maybe even security problems (like it did for openssl).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`[` is synonym of the `test` command and it is simultaneously a *bash builtin* and separate command. But `[[` is a *bash keyword* and works in some versions only. So for reasons of portability you are better off using single `[]` or `test`

```
[ -w "/home/durrantm" ] && echo "writable"
```

Comment: `[`is POSIX builtin or Bash builtin ?

Comment: @Sandburg POSIX is a standard, so it can't have built-ins. It doesn't define if something should be built into the interpreter or not, just what it has to do. These rules apply to both forms, `test` and `[` alike. If a shell can do the evaluation on its own, that saves you a process and makes it somewhat faster, but the result has to be the same.

Comment: @Bachsau that still doesn't answer Sandburg's question as to whether or not the behavior of `[` is defined by POSIX and therefore maximally portable (which seems to be the entire point of this question if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @Sandburg (and to anyone else stumbling across this): **Yes, it looks like both `[` and `test` [are POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).** There seems to be neither "recommended", though the only difference(?) I can spot between them is that `test` "shall not recognize the "--" argument \[as a delimiter indicating the end of options\]" (?- implying that "--" _is_ recognized as end-of-arguments for `[`, which I can't actually come up with a good test case for anyway. But I digress. Use which you will. IMO, `[` looks elegant,but `test` isclearly a command)

Answer (score 35):

Yes, there are differences. The most portable are `test` or `[ ]`. These are both part of the [POSIX `test` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

The `if ... fi` construct is also [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and should be completely portable.

The `[[ ]]` is a `ksh` feature that is also present in some versions of `bash` ([all modern ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168255/is-test-or-or-more-portable-both-between-bash-shells-and-between-other-shel/168261#comment276995_168261)), in `zsh` and perhaps in others but is not present in `sh` or `dash` or the various other simpler shells.

So, to make your scripts portable, use `[ ]`, `test` or `if ... fi`.

Comment: Just to note, `bash` and `zsh` have supported `[[` for a very long time (`bash` added it in the late 90s, `zsh` no later than 2000, and I'd be surprised if it *ever* lacked support), so you are unlikely to encounter a version of either without `[[`. Encountering a different POSIX-compliant shell (such as `dash`) is far more likely.

Comment: One interesting feature of `[[` is that parameter expansions don't have to be quoted: `[[-f $file]]` event works if `$file` contains whitespace characters.

Comment: @helpermethod also, builtin regular expressions `[[ $a =~ ^reg.*exp.*$' ]]`

Answer (score 21):

Please note, that `[] && cmd` is not the same as `if .. fi` construction.

Sometimes its behaviour its pretty similar and you can use `[] && cmd` instead of `if .. fi`. But only sometimes. If you have more then one command to execute if condition or you need `if .. else .. fi` be careful and whatch the logic.

A couple of examples:

```
[ -z "$VAR" ] && ls file || echo wiiii
```

Is not the same as

```
if [ -z $VAR ] ; then
  ls file
else
  echo wiii
fi
```

because if `ls` will fail, `echo` will be executed which will not happen with `if`.

Another example:

```
[ -z "$VAR" ] && ls file && echo wiii
```

is not the same as

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ] ; then
   ls file
   echo $wiii
fi
```

though this construction will act the same

```
[ -z "$VAR" ] && { ls file ; echo wiii ; }
```

please note `;` after echo is important and must be there.

So resuming statement above we can say

`[] && cmd` == if first command is successful then execute the next one

`if .. fi` == if condition (which may be the test command as well) then execute command(s)

So for portability between `[` and `[[` use `[` only.

`if` is POSIX compatible. So if you have to choose between `[` and `if` choose looking at your task and expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm probably just being dense, but I'm not seeing what the difference would be... could you please give an example where those two constructions would give different results?

Comment: @evilsoup, updated. May be I'm not the best explainer, though I hope it will be clear now.

Comment: Very good points, rush. I suppose a safe form of your 1st example would be: `[ -z "$VAR" ] && { ls file; true; }  || echo wiiii`. It's a bit more verbose, but it's still shorter than the `if...fi` construction.

Comment: Made the question be about [ vs [[ vs test and not also about if...fi vs && to make it be ONE question.  Unfortunately doing that makes this answer seem off-point.  Apologies for not getting the question m ore focused initially that led to this.  Live and (try to) learn. :)

Comment: I downvoted because a) this is mainly a good answer, but it is an answer to different question. b) you present `[` and `if` as subtitutes, but they aren't. It's actually the `&&` that's replacing the `if`. `[` executes some code and returns a status, much like `ls` and `grep` would. `if` branches execution depending on the return status of the command (statement) given after the if, it could be any command (statement). `&&` executes the next statement only if the previous one returned 0, much like a simple `if..then..fi`.

Comment: @gnp, well. a) please check comment from Michael. There is a short explanation that initially there was a different question. I just left the answer for history. b) The answer was mostly about difference between `&& .. ||` and `if .. else .. fi`.

Comment: @rush you're right, I missed the edit history there. My apologies. As I said, this is mainly a good answer, so I rectified my vote.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually the `&&` that is replacing the `if`, not the `test`: an `if` statement in shell scripting tests whether a command returned a "successful" (zero) exit status; in your example, the command is `[`.

So, there are actually two things you are varying here: the command used to run the test, and the syntax used to execute code based on the result of that test.

Test commands:

- `test` is [a standardised command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for evaluating properties of strings and files; in your example, you are running the command `test -w /home/durrantm`
- `[` is an alias of that command, equally standardised, which has a mandatory last argument of `]` in order to look like a bracketed expression; don't be fooled, it's still just a command (you may even find that your system has a file called `/bin/[`)
- `[[` is an extended version of the test command built into some shells, but not part of the same POSIX standard; it includes extra options which you are not using here

Conditional expressions:

- The `&&` operator ([standardised here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_06)) performs a logical AND operation, by evaluating two commands and returning 0 (which represents true) if they both return 0; it will only evaluate the second command if the first one returned zero, so it can be used as a simple conditional
- The `if ... then ... fi` construct ([standardised here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07)) uses the same method of judging "truth", but allows for a compound list of statements in the `then` clause, rather than the single command afforded by an `&&` short-circuit, and provides `elif` and `else` clauses, which are hard to write using only `&&` and `||`. *Note that there are no brackets around the condition in an `if` statement*.

So, the following are all equally portable, and entirely equivalent, renderings of your example:

- `test -w /home/durrantm && echo "writable"`
- `[ -w /home/durrantm ] && echo "writable"`
- `if test -w /home/durrantm; then echo "writable"; fi`
- `if [ -w /home/durrantm ]; then echo "writable"; fi`

While the following are also equivalent, but less portable due to the non-standard nature of `[[`:

- `[[ -w /home/durrantm ]] && echo "writable"`
- `if [[ -w /home/durrantm ]]; then echo "writable"; fi`

Comment: Yes I removed the if....fi part to make this be 1 question.

Answer (score 7):

For portability, use `test` / `[`. But if you don't need the portability, for the sake of the sanity of yourself and others reading your script use `[[`. :)

Also see `What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?` in the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Answer (score 7):

If you want portability outside the Bourne-like world, then:

```
test -w /home/durrantm && echo writable
```

is the most portable. It works in shells of the Bourne, `csh` and `rc` families.

```
test -w /home/durrantm && echo "writable"
```

would output `"writable"` instead of `writable` in shells of the `rc` family (`rc`, `es`, `akanga`, where `"` is not special).

```
[ -w /home/durrantm ] && echo writable
```

would not work in shells of the `csh` or `rc` families on systems that don't have a `[` command in `$PATH` (some have been known to have `test` but not its `[` alias).

```
if [ -w /home/durrantm ]; then echo writabe; fi
```

only works in shells of the Bourne family.

```
[[ -w /home/durrantm ]] && echo writable
```

only works in `ksh` (where it originated), `zsh` and `bash` (all 3 in the Bourne family).

None would work in the `fish` shell where you need:

```
[ -w /home/durrantm ]; and echo writable
```

or:

```
if [ -w /home/durrantm ]; echo writable; end
```

Answer (score 0):

My most important reason for choosing either `if foo; then bar; fi` or `foo && bar` is whether the exit status of the whole command is important.

compare:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
foo && bar
do_baz
```

with:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if foo; then bar; fi
do_baz
```

You might think they do the same; however if `foo` fails (or is false, depending on your point of view) then in the first example do_baz will not be executed, as the script will have exited... The `set -e` instructs the shell to exit immediately if any command return a false status. Very useful if you're doing things like:

```
cd /some/directory
rm -rf *
```

You don't want the script to continue running if the `cd` fails for whatever reason.

Comment: No a failing `foo` will not abort the script in either case. That's a special case for `set -e` (when the command is evaluated as a condition (to the left of some &&/|| or in if/while/until/elsif... conditions). A failing `bar` would exit the shell in both cases.

Comment: You want `cd /some/directory && rm -rf -- *` or `cd /some/directory || exit; rm -rf -- *` (still doesn't remove hidden files). I personally don't like the idea of using `set -e` as an excuse not to make an effort to write correct code.