# What is the most portable syntax for `if` statements?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, test

(NOTE: There is [a very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168255/is-test-or-if-fi-or-more-portable-what-about-test-vs-vs), asked yesterday oddly enough, but it doesn't cover the main syntaxes I'm concerned with.  If I were to update the other question to include them it might render the answers no longer valid, so I'll focus here on what was missed in the other question.  Anyone who wants the whole picture should look at both questions and their accepted answers.)

I typically write my if statements as follows:

```
if [[ -z "$SOMETHING" ]]; then
  # blah blah blah
fi
```

which works well for me under Bash and Z Shell, but I recently came across [a syntax which drops the square brackets entirely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/3358):

```
if command -v given-command > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo given-command is available
else
  echo given-command is not available
fi
```

Is the version without any brackets portable?  How does it compare to the options presented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168255/3358)?

Is my standard version mainly only supported on Bash and Z Shell (like the `[[ -w /home/durrantm ]] && echo "writable"` version mentioned on that other question)?

Comment: Yes, I've update my (referenced) question to only be about `[` vs `[[` vs `test` and now this question can just be about `if...fi` portability.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant:  excellent.  After reading muru's answer I realized your question (and maybe mine too) dealt with both issues without specifically delineating them.  I thought of commenting to that effect there, but I'm glad you noticed it too and took action first.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there some shell in which `$"SOMETHING"` works, or is that just a typo for `"$SOMETHING"`?

Comment: @Scott: pretty sure that was a typo... at least I can't see any reason for it other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your standard version is not POSIX-standard, as the question you linked to notes. However, the following is:

```
if some-command args; then ...
```

I'd say this is the only portable form of `if`, since, this is what `if` is all about. `if` does something if `some-command` (which can be a function, a shell builtin, or an executable<sup>1</sup>) returns `0` for the arguments and input it is run with.

When you run `if [ ]` or `if [[ ]]`, `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` are programs or shell builtins which return `0` if the condition tests true. If you convert `[` to `test`, you'll see that you're always running the form without the brackets:

```
if [ ... ]
# same as 
if /bin/test ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>To be more precise, let's look at how the `if` construct [is defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07):

> The **if** command shall execute a *compound-list* and use its exit status
>   to determine whether to execute another *compound-list*.
>
> The format for the **if** construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> if compound-list 
> then
>     compound-list
> [elif compound-list 
> then
>     compound-list] ...
> [else
>     compound-list]
> fi
> ```

Note that a [*compound list*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) is not the same as a [*compound command*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

Comment: Aha: now the syntax actually makes sense...  I don't think anyone dealt with `if /bin/test` as one of the examples in the answers to the other question.  Your answer seems to fill in the missing details quite nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: @iconoclast That could be because `test` is also a shell-builtin, and so `if test` would always use the builtin. That's probably why nobody covers the case of `/bin/test`.

Comment: I didn't notice anyone dealing with `if test` either... but perhaps I just missed it.

Comment: @iconoclast There's a cameo in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168307/70524) (fourth-from-last bullet point).