# Difference between `[[ $a -lt 2 ]]` and `(( $a < 2 ))`

Tags: bash, test

Is there any significant difference between using `[[ $a -lt 2 ]]` and `(( $a < 2 ))`?

For example, is one of them faster or more POSIX compliant than the other?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) [Is test or [ or [[ more portable both between bash shells and between other shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168255/)

Comment: `(( $a < 2 ))` is a valid *command* in `bash`, distinct from the *expression* `$(( $a < 2 ))`.

Comment: also related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373

Comment: @chepner one learns something new each day. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is POSIX-compatible. In a POSIX shell, you can use the command `[ "$a" -lt 2 ]` or the *expression* `$(( a < 2 ))`.

In `bash`, the former is simply the conditional command supporting a superset of the conditional expressions that `[` supports, and the latter is a standalone command that exits with status 0 if the enclosed arithmetic expression is non-zero, or 1 otherwise. Other than readability, there is no significant difference between the two when used properly.

Comment: `(( ))` and `$(( ))` would perhaps make it easier to mix other arithmetic in, if that's ever needed?

Comment: Is `[` available in any shell? If there would be a shell where `[` is not built-in then ``$(( ))`` could be significant faster.

Comment: @rudimeier In theory `[` can be external but in practice it's always built in.